# Display an image using jetty web server from byte array

Tags: java, jetty

I have content of an image in a byte array, in a jetty servlet class. How could I display this image in a browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have something similar to this inside your sevlet

```
byte[] imageBytes = ...
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpg");// or png or gif, etc
response.setHeader("Content-Length", imageBytes.lenght);
response.getOutputStream().write(imageBytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code worked. Thanks to "David Hofmann".

```
//data is the content of the image in binary
response.setContentType("image/jpg");// or png or gif, etc
response.setContentLength(data.length);
response.getOutputStream().write(data);
```