# Draw shape in Java and return to browser within HTTP request

Tags: javascript, java, canvas, awt

I have a Node app which draws x,y graphs and streams this back to the browser. I use HTML canvas and to stream the image back to the UI I do:

```
// create the canvas, set size and draw the x,y points
// ...
// ...

var buf = canvas.toBuffer();
var graph = buf.toString('base64');

var data = JSON.stringify({
    graph: graph
});

var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'image/png'
};

res.writeHead(200, headers);
res.end(data);
```

Now I want to rewrite this functionality in Java. I'm thinking to use `java.awt.Graphics2D` for this purpose. I'm create the image here:

```
Graphics g;
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

g2.setColor(Color.red);
g2.drawRect(10,10,100,100);
```

How can I then return this to the browser within a HTTP request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple, straightforward approach is:

1. Write an [embedded Jetty application](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/embedding-jetty.html).
2. Convert Graphics2D instance to a [RenderedImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/image/RenderedImage.html) interface.
3. Write the graphics object to [a known image format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html) via [ImageIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html).
4. Export the rendered image to the browser via a [custom handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17432061/59087).

---

This could resemble:

```
package org.eclipse.jetty.embedded;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler;

public class ImageHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    public ImageHandler() { }

    public void handle( final String target,
                        final Request baseRequest,
                        final HttpServletRequest request,
                        final HttpServletResponse response )
      throws IOException, ServletException
    {
      final byte[] image = getImage();
      response.setHeader( "Content-Type", "image/png" );
      response.setHeader( "Content-Length", image.length );
      response.setStatus( HttpServletResponse.SC_OK );
      response.getOutputStream().write( image );

      baseRequest.setHandled( true );
    }
}
```

And the `getImage()` method:

```
public byte[] getImage() throws IOException {
    final int width = getWidth();
    final int width = getHeight();
    final BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage( width, height, TYPE_INT_RGB );
    final Graphics2D graphics = createGraphics2D();
    graphics.drawImage( image, null, null );

    final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write( image, "png", baos );
    baos.flush();

    final byte[] result = baos.toByteArray();
    baos.close();

    return result;
}
```

---

What goes into the method `Graphics2D createGraphics2D() { ... }` is entirely up to you. The image dimensions (width and height) must also be specified. The `TYPE_INT_RGB` constant comes from `BufferedImage`.

---

Note that it is possible to combine the steps of writing via ImageIO and exporting to the response output stream. This would write the image directly to the browser, without first creating an array, and therefore improve the perceived rendering speed.